# how to pandas parse json that was previously saved

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have saved a pandas dataframe into csv, and read it back in. But I observed the json data becomes like the following:

```
"[{u'f1': 1000, u'f2': 500}]"
```

I noticed that using `json.loads` does not work. Does anyone could please help to answer why

1. It has put `u` in front of every field name
2. The quotes are swapped, since I experimented and found that only `json.loads('[{"f1": 1000}]')` works, not `json.loads("[{'f1': 1000}]")` nor `json.loads('[{"f1": 1000}]')`

Comment: Can you post an example of the original `DataFrame`?

Comment: That's not JSON. That's a Python literal. How exactly did produce that output? Saving Pandas to a CSV file does not promise anything about JSON.

Comment: You did not mention how you produced 'json'  from a DataFrame, but the way to do it is with the 'to_json' method  documented at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html.  There are a number of other such methods for exporting the content of a DataFrame to other formats and they are listed at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not JSON. That's Python 2 literal syntax.

You could load it again as a Python literal with the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[{u'f1': 1000, u'f2': 500}]")
[{u'f1': 1000, u'f2': 500}]
```

giving you a Python list with a single dictionary in it; each key is a `unicode` string object; because the keys use ASCII characters only, you can use a regular string as a key to address these too:

```
>>> result = ast.literal_eval("[{u'f1': 1000, u'f2': 500}]")
>>> result[0]
{u'f1': 1000, u'f2': 500}
>>> result[0]['f1']
1000
```

JSON would use double quotes and no prefixes before the strings, while Python `unicode` string objects can use either `'` or `"` (depending on the contents) and have the `u` prefix. There are other differences too; Python uses `True` and `False`, JSON lowercases those to `true` and `false`, and `None` in Python is `null` in JSON.